# Run python on pc without python installed using anaconda built in tools

Tags: python

Is there any way to make a python code run on a computer that doesn't have python installed using tools that come with anaconda (py2exe is not an option for me because it isn't a part of anaconda and needs to be downloaded separately)

I am using python 3.5.

Comment: I suppose you could run it from a flash drive, but you need a python interpreter to turn code into what the computer understands.

Comment: I've had some success running from a removable hard drive. It takes some time setting up but if you can replicate the development environment it should run pretty seamlessly.